# flutter stack widget position same across other screen sizes

Tags: flutter

I m trying to develop image editor. It takes input from the user and display it over screen . I have attached few screenshots . I have used stack and positioned widget to achieve this . And i have tried flutter_screen_util also . But with the different screen , position widget is changing its place .
I have developed this app on 2400x1080 resoultion , and i have changed stack widget position accordingly. i want the common code to work on different screen as well .

```
     Positioned(
         left: 94,
         bottom: 148,
       
        child: Text(
          widget.score.isEmpty || widget.score == null
              ? ''
              : score, //score gets updated from TextEditingController()
          style:  defaultTextStyle,
        ),
      ).
```

Images :
[working fine on 2400x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmNCS.jpg)
[this is on different screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWGHh.png)

Comment: Stack is not the correct widget here. Try going with Row or Wrap.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with stack then never use raw values like in your example you should calculate the screen size and then place them:

```
Positioned(
         left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/8, //This will place the widget at a distance of 1/8th of the screen width so just change the ratio and place it.
         bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/12, //this is for 1/12th of screen height
       
        child: Text(
          widget.score.isEmpty || widget.score == null
              ? ''
              : score, //score gets updated from TextEditingController()
          style:  defaultTextStyle,
        ),
      ).
```

Though may not be good in every situation but far better then your raw values

Comment: even after using MediaQuery also , widget is not at right place . Is there any way we can place widget using image co ordinates

Comment: sorry, I don't know :(

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: X(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class X extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        Text("for scoring "),
        _underlineWidget(context, "96"),
        Text(" % in class "),
        _underlineWidget(context, "10"),
        Text(" of year in "),
        _underlineWidget(context, "2020"),
        _underlineWidget(context, " Rotary "),
        Text(" School located in "),
        _underlineWidget(context, "Bengal"),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _underlineWidget(context, String text) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(text),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.teal),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, image will have fixed image . Only dashed part should be filled using textEdtiting control .

Comment: If you need to print it as pdf, then it is better to use https://pub.dev/packages/pdf. This will allow you to print general flutter widgets. And will make it look like an image. If you are trying to position your text on top of an image then it will be a lot of work for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your stack with a `Container()` and give it the wished `width`.